# Send Email to second manager if the item hasn't been approved after one day

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I am new to SharePoint and have difficulty understanding the approval process. We have a list with all the leave requests and on this list is a workflow that sends a email to the manager as soon as a item has been created.

What we would like to do is add a second manager and send a email to him after one day if the first manager has not approved the item.

Is this even possible and how would I do this in SharePoint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In you workflow you can set a timer. Add a one-day timer, then do a IF on the approval status. If it's not approved then send an email to the second manager.

Comment: I'm not sure where you set the timer. From SharePoint designer or in SharePoint itself